sqlite trigger not firing in a in Memory Database when testing room db with junit4
i have a need in my app ,
my android app stores requests
i have tests  to test my room db , i have issue with one test.
the test assert that when very old requests are inserted then a trigger fires to delete them .
the problem is i have tried the code in main activity and seem to be working, but failing on junit
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Log.d(TAG, " TEST...")
        val requestDao = RequestsDataBase.getDataBase(this@TEST.applicationContext).RequestDao()

    val nowUnix = Date().time / 1000 // seconds
    println("now unix /1000 $nowUnix")
    println("now unix ${nowUnix * 1000}")
    val oldExpired = nowUnix - 86400 - 10
    println("old $oldExpired")
    requestDao.insert(Request("a1", "", oldExpired))
    requestDao.insert(Request("a2", "a", nowUnix))
    requestDao.insert(Request("a9", "a1", nowUnix - 200))

    val data = requestDao.read()

    for (one in data) {
        println("-- $one")
    }
}

but  the problem is that inside the tests the test failed and the old requests do not get  deleted
fun assert_deletion_of_old_requests(){
        val nowUnix = Date().time / 1000 // seconds
        println("now unix /1000 $nowUnix")
        println("now unix ${nowUnix * 1000}")
        val oldExpired = nowUnix - 86400 - 10
        println("old $oldExpired")
        requestDao.insert(Request("a1", "", oldExpired))
        requestDao.insert(Request("a2", "a", nowUnix))
        requestDao.insert(Request("a9", "a1", nowUnix - 200))

        println("waiting start")
        val start = Date().time / 1000 // now in seconds
        var now = Date().time / 1000 // now in seconds
        while (now - start  < 10){
            now = Date().time / 1000
        }
        println("endwaiting")
        val data = requestDao.read()

        for (one in data) {
            println("-- $one")
        }
        assert(data.size == 2)

}

i have tried adding waiting but it's not working
